What is the difference between using the <T extends HTMLElement> type and using <HTMLElement>?
I have a question while studying for TS.
I created a useScroll custom hook.
When defining the type in this hook,
what is the difference between using the  type and using ?
export default function useScroll<T extends HTMLElement>(
  handleScrollDown: () => void,
  handleScrollUp: () => void,
): RefObject<T> {
  const ref = useRef<T>(null);

export default function useScroll<HTMLElement>(
  handleScrollDown: () => void,
  handleScrollUp: () => void,
  isUsable = true,
): RefObject<HTMLElement> {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current;
    if (!isUsable || !element) return;

    const handleWheel = (event: WheelEvent) => {
      if (event.deltaY < 0) {
        handleScrollUp();
      } else if (event.deltaY > 0) {
        handleScrollDown();
      }
    };

    element.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);

    return () => {
      element.removeEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
    };
  }, [handleScrollDown, handleScrollUp, isUsable]);

  return ref;
}


and in the latter method,
"element.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel)" causes this type error.
'addEventListener' does not exist on Type 'NonNullable'
Why does this happen??
I looked up a book about generic types, but I didn't understand it well, so I hope I can understand it easily.

I am not sure, whether this line is enough for TS: if (!isUsable || !element) return;. I usually do the opposite: if (element) { ... }. Otherwise, I don't see the point in parametrizing a method with a fixed type: useScroll<HTMLElement>. useScroll<T extends HTMLElement> allows the user to specify the type of HTMLElement, e.g. HTMLDivElement. This might be helpful for some use cases.

<T extends HTMLElement> extends the HTMLElement type, which allows you to add more properties to its contract.
addEventListener and removeEventListener are in fact functions added to subtypes of HTMLElement. For instance it exists on HTMLLabelElement. Defining it generically to work on any type of HTMLElement will be tricky so I suggest you use a more precise type to match your need.
To help you understand, it would have to be something like this:
export default function useScroll<T extends HTMLElement & {
  addEventListener: (eventType: 'wheel', handler: (event: WheelEvent) => void) => void,
  removeEventListener: (eventType: 'wheel', handler: (event: WheelEvent) => void) => void,
}>(

